# how to find frequency of occurence (large number) from an integer array

Tags: java

I want to find the frequency of occurence for large value, like in the array largest value is 98, I want to find how many times it is repeating. Help me guys

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int numbers[] = new int[]{32,43,53,25,98,54,32,65,63,98,43,23,25,98};
    int largest = numbers[0];
    for (int i=1; i< numbers.length; i++) {
        if(numbers[i] > largest)
            largest = numbers[i];
    }
    System.out.println("Largest Number is : " + largest);
}
```

Comment: hint: think what you could additionally do when number[i] is = instead of > of the current largest (and you will need a variable to store the frequency)

Comment: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/5221149) --- I am being nice and interpreting "Help me guys" as a request, not an order, because giving orders when you want help will just get you [expletives](https://www.google.com/search?q=list+of+all+expletives) back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a counter that you increment each time you see the largest value and reset each time you find a new larger value:

```
int largest = numbers[0];
int counter = 1;

for(int i=1; i< numbers.length; i++)
{
        if(numbers[i] > largest) {
                largest = numbers[i];
                counter = 1;
        } elseif (numbers[i] == largest) {
                counter++;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if this is a homework question, so I'll try to help by giving you a design in pseudocode rather than Java.

Suppose you're looking at an element.  There are three cases:

1. It's smaller than the previous max.  Ignore it.
2. It's bigger than the previous max (or it's the first item).  Make it the new max.  As of now, its count must be 1.
3. It's equal to the previous max.  Increment the max's count by 1.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a `count` variable. Reset this variable to one whenever you find a new largest value, and increment it whenever the value at your current index is equal to the largest number that you found so far.

Answer (score 0):

A conventional way to go about such a problem is to use a hash table. The first time you see an element, put it into the hash table with count = 1. Each time you see the same element after that, increase its count by 1. At the end, loop through the keys of the hash table and find the key which is the greatest, then output that key and its associated value (i.e. its count).

There may be solutions which are more efficient in some sense, but I'm guessing they are also more complicated. You can say whether you need to consider that.

Comment: Counting every distinct value is overkill if you only need count of largest value, and I wouldn't say that [just counting the largest value](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46699200/5221149) is "more complicated". It's actually less complicated.

Comment: OK, fair enough.